# Can I circumvent the minimum investment amount on mutual fund if I am gifted a share of that fund?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, vanguard

Vanguard has [Information Technology Index Fund](https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/profile/VITAX) that require hefty $100,000 minimum to start investing. If a friend of mine donate(gift) me one share (current price $203.83) and I give him cash same amount, will it open the fund for me and then I can do dollar cost averaging. Does Vanguard permits that?

Comment: I would think that would not be allowable.  Unless the gift is over 100K, they will probably require the recipient to liquidate the fund.

Comment: How does one go about _gifting_ a share of a mutual fund to a friend? Mutual fund shares exist only on the books of the fund and must be bought from the fund, or redeemed for cash from the fund.  Mutual fund shares cannot be sold on the open market (or in a private transaction between a seller and a buyer); nor can they be gifted to anybody. Everything miss go through the books of the fund company.

Comment: I click on your link - first thing I read is *Also available as an ETF (starting at the price of one share)*. Is there any issue, at all? What's the importance of this mutual funds over any funds following the index?

Answer (score 8):

It is **highly** unlikely that Vanguard would allow this (either the "gift"/ sale of the initial share or the subsequent investment of less than the minimum).  But since this is a company/ fund policy rather than something universal, you'd need to ask Vanguard what they'd allow.

However, on the page you link to, right under the minimum investment, there is the note

> Available as an [ETF](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/vgt) (starting at the price of one share).

If you follow that link, you'll go to a page describing the equivalent ETF product that you can buy on the secondary market.  Your broker is unlikely to have any sort of minimum investment requirement for an ETF though you may not be able to buy fractional shares and may (depending on country and broker) need to pay a commission on trades.

Comment: With many brokers having zero commissions, the benefit of a mutual fund seems small, if any, when compared to the same ETF. In this case both have a .10% expense. Aside from the fund taking round dollar amounts once past the minimum, I don't see the benefit.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica - Agreed, at least in the US.

Comment: Absolutely, an ETF is usually the way to go. Vanguard is very pro-consumer  and pro-index fund (it's John Bogle's company for Pete's sake) so they will provide a means to access it, "walled gardens for the rich" isn't really their format. Sorta like "First Class" isn't really Southwest's format.